# How to detect/disable Standard or Enterprise features in SQL Server Developer edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Is there a way to

1. Check if enterprise functions are used in a database in developer edition
2. Disable the enterprise functionality for certain databases in a developer edition.

Use case:

Developers tend to develop.. they don't care about any licensing or pricing. And in a lot of cases you shouldn't put a brake on their creativity. This is also why SQL Server Developer edition was made.. everything just works.
But then.. you move your software to production and ERROR..  some developer used a property or setting or design that works in the developer edition, but not in the standard edition.   It is very hard and error-prone to manually run over the entire check list of functionalities and see if any are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-persisted-sku-features-transact-sql) on each database
For example, one of my databases on one server gives

```
feature_name    feature_id
Compression     100
```

Also [sp_blitz](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit) will report on this for you